# How to return a tuple inside an EitherT

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers, scalaz7

I'm using Scalaz 7's EitherT to construct for-comprehensions that blend State and \/.  So far so good; I get something that's basically:

```
State[MyStateType, MyLeftType \/ MyRightType]
```

and that allows me to build for-comprehensions that have nice variables on the left side of the <-.

But I can't figure out how to return tuples from a state action.  Single results are just fine - in the code below, "val comprehension" is exactly what I want to happen.

But things fall apart when I want to return a tuple; "val otherComprehension" won't let me do

```
(a, b) <- comprehension
```

It looks like it expects the left side of the \/ to be a Monoid and I don't understand why.  What am I missing?

(Scalaz 7 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, Scala 2.10.2)

```
object StateProblem {
  case class MyStateType
  case class MyRightType
  case class MyLeftType

  type StateWithFixedStateType[+A] = State[MyStateType, A]
  type EitherTWithFailureType[F[+_], A] = EitherT[F, MyLeftType, A]
  type CombinedStateAndFailure[A] = EitherTWithFailureType[StateWithFixedStateType, A]

  def doSomething: CombinedStateAndFailure[MyRightType] = {
    val x = State[MyStateType, MyLeftType \/ MyRightType] {
      case s => (s, MyRightType().right)
    }
    EitherT[StateWithFixedStateType, MyLeftType, MyRightType](x)
  }

  val comprehension = for {
    a <- doSomething
    b <- doSomething
  } yield (a, b)

  val otherComprehension = for {
    // this gets a compile error:
    // could not find implicit value for parameter M: scalaz.Monoid[com.seattleglassware.StateProblem.MyLeftType]
    (x, y) <- comprehension

    z <- doSomething
  } yield (x, y, z)
}
```

Edit: I've added evidence that MyLeftType is a monad, even though it's not.  In my real code, MyLeftType is a case class (called EarlyReturn), so I can provide a zero, but append only works if one of the arguments is a zero:

```
  implicit val partialMonoidForEarlyReturn = new Monoid[EarlyReturn] {
    case object NoOp extends EarlyReturn
    def zero = NoOp
    def append(a: EarlyReturn, b: => EarlyReturn) =
      (a, b) match {
        case (NoOp, b) => b
        case (a, NoOp) => a
        case _         => throw new RuntimeException("""this isnt really a Monoid, I just want to use it on the left side of a \/""")
      }
  }
```

I'm not convinced this is a good idea, but it's solving the problem.

Comment: There's something strange going on in the way 2.10.1+ desugars the `for`-comprehension here—see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17424763/334519) for a simplified version of the same issue.

Comment: And to be clear, this is happening because filtering `EitherT` (or `\/`) requires a monoid instance for the left side, and for some reason 2.10.2 is sticking a filter operation in this `for`-comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I note in a comment above, the problem is that the desugared version of your second `for`-comprehension involves a filtering operation in 2.10.2 (and 2.10.1, but not 2.10.0), and it's not possible to filter `EitherT` (or plain old `\/`) without a monoid instance for the type on the left side.

It's pretty easy to see why the monoid is necessary in the following example:

```
val x: String \/ Int = 1.right
val y: String \/ Int = x.filter(_ < 0)
```

What is `y`? It's clear that it has to be some kind of "empty" `String \/ Int`, and since `\/` is right-biased, we know that it can't be a value on that side. So we need a zero for the left side, and the monoid instance for `String` provides this—it's just the empty string:

```
assert(y == "".left)
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17427067/334519) to [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17424763/334519) about tuple patterns in `for`-comprehensions, the behavior you're seeing in 2.10.2 is correct and intended—the apparently completely unnecessary call to `withFilter` is here to stay.

You can use the workaround in Petr Pudlák's answer, but it's also worth noting that the following sugar-free version is also pretty clear and concise:

```
val notAnotherComprehension = comprehension.flatMap {
  case (x, y) => doSomething.map((x, y, _))
}
```

This is more or less what I would naïvely expect the `for`-comprehension to desugar to, anyway (and I'm [not the only one](https://twitter.com/coltfred/status/352198680608116737)).

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing the cause, I found a possible workaround:

```
for {
  //(x, y) <- comprehension
  p <- comprehension

  z <- doSomething
} yield (p._1, p._2, z)
```

or perhaps slightly better

```
for {
  //(x, y) <- comprehension
  p <- comprehension
  (x, y) = p

  z <- doSomething
} yield (x, y, z)
```

It's not very nice, but does the job.

(I really appreciate that you made a self-contained, working example of the problem.)

Comment: Instead of the x = p._1; y = p._2; you can just do (x, y) = p.  Feels strange that you need to do it on another line (link and comment from @TravisBrown has useful info).