# New desugaring behavior in Scala 2.10.1

Tags: scala, syntax, filtering, monads, for-comprehension

Suppose I have this monadic class:

```
case class Foo[A](xs: List[A]) {
  def map[B](f: A => B) = Foo(xs map f)
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Foo[B]) = Foo(xs flatMap f.andThen(_.xs))
  def withFilter(p: A => Boolean) = {
    println("Filtering!")
    Foo(xs filter p)
  }
}
```

The following is from a 2.10.0 REPL session:

```
scala> for { (a, b) <- Foo(List(1 -> "x")) } yield a
res0: Foo[Int] = Foo(List(1))
```

And here's the same thing in 2.10.1:

```
scala> for { (a, b) <- Foo(List(1 -> "x")) } yield a
Filtering!
res0: Foo[Int] = Foo(List(1))
```

This is completely unexpected (to me), and leads to particularly confusing errors in cases where filtering requires additional constraints (such as Scalaz's [`\/` or `EitherT`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17418165/334519)).

I wasn't able to find any discussion of this change in the [2.10.1 release notes](http://www.scala-lang.org/2.10.1). Can someone point out where and why this new desugaring behavior was introduced?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The story is more complex than that, and it's in fact a 2.10.0 regression that was plugged there.

The "no-`withFilter`" behavior was introduced in [c82ecab](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/c82ecab), and because of things like [SI-6968](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6968), this was reverted partially [#1893](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/1893). Further adaptations followed ([SI-6646](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6646), [SI-7183](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7183))

The takeaway sentence you're looking for is :

> The parser can't assume that a pattern (a, b) will match, as results
>   of .isInstanceOf[Tuple2] can't be statically known until after the
>   typer.